# Need to obtain match between specified delimiters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match specific `tags` between double block quote delimiters within a sentence :

```
Look for `foo="x"` ONLY between the specific double block quote delimiters  [[foo="x"|bar="y"|baz="z"]]
```

Using the following regex matches also the `foo="x"` outside the delimiters :

```
(?:(foo|bar|baz)="([^"]+)")+
```

I've tried adding the positive lookbehind : `(?<=\[\[)` but it only returns me the first `foo="x"` within the bockquotes but ignores the `bar="y"` and `baz="z"` matches.

```js
const regex = /(?:(foo|bar|baz)="([^"]+)")+/gm;
const str = `Look for \`foo="x"\` ONLY between the specific double block quote delimiters  [[foo="x"|bar="y"|baz="z"]]`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: A common work around may work - `/(foo|bar|baz)="([^"]+)"(?=[^\][]*]])/g` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/zEPcOV/1)). Are you extracting or replacing the matches?

Comment: This may work: `(?:foo|bar|baz)="[^"]+"(?=(?:(?!\[\[).)*]])` and will also allow `[` and `]` inside `[[...]]`

Comment: Well, another idea is to use a two step approach: 1) get the Group 1 value with `/\[\[((foo|bar|baz)="([^"]+)"(?:\|(foo|bar|baz)="([^"]+)")*)]]/`, 2) use `/(foo|bar|baz)="([^"]+)"/g` to extract the necessary values from Group 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your strings inside `[[` and `]]` don't have `[` and `]` a simple

```
/(foo|bar|baz)="([^"]+)"(?=[^\][]*]])/g
```

will work for you. The `(?=[^\][]*]])` part will make sure there are 0 or more chars other than `[` and `]` and then `]` are immediately to the right of the current location. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sjhhXI/2).

The safest solution includes two steps: 1) get the Group 1 value with `/\[\[((foo|bar|baz)="([^"]+)"(?:\|(foo|bar|baz)="([^"]+)")*)]]/` (or a simpler but less precise but more *generic* `/\[\[\w+="[^"]+"(?:\|\w+="[^"]+")*]]/g`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lTYILZ/1)), and 2) use `/(foo|bar|baz)="([^"]+)"/g` (or `/(\w+)="([^"]+)"/g`) to extract the necessary values from Group 1.

```js
const x = '(foo|bar|baz)="([^"]+)"';                         // A key-value pattern block
const regex = new RegExp(`\\[\\[(${x}(?:\\|${x})*)]]`, 'g'); // Extracting the whole `[[]]`
const str = `Look for \`foo="x"\` ONLY between the specific double block quote delimiters  [[foo="x"|bar="y"|baz="z"]]`;
let m;
while (m = regex.exec(str)) {
    let results = [...m[1].matchAll(/(foo|bar|baz)="([^"]+)"/g)]; // Grabbing individual matches 
    console.log(Array.from(results, m => [m[1],m[2]]));
}
```

The `\[\[((foo|bar|baz)="([^"]+)"(?:\|(foo|bar|baz)="([^"]+)")*)]]` pattern will match

- `\[\[`  - `[[`
- `((foo|bar|baz)="([^"]+)"(?:\|(foo|bar|baz)="([^"]+)")*)` - Group 1:

  - `(foo|bar|baz)` - `foo`, `bar` or `baz`
  - `=` - `=`
  - `"([^"]+)"` - `"`, 1 or more chars other than `"` and a `"`
  - `(?:\|(foo|bar|baz)="([^"]+)")*` - 0 or more repetitions of `|` and the pattern described above
- `]]` - `]]` substring.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sjhhXI/1).

Answer (score 2):

Try slightly another definition of your requirements:

- match *name="value"*, with capturing groups for both *name* and *value*,
- before the *name* there should be:

  - either double opening bracket (`[[`),
  - or a vertical bar (`|`),
- after the *value* (and closing double quote) there should be:

  - either double closing bracket (`]]`),
  - or a vertical bar (`|`).

Then the regex can be as follows:

```
(?:\[\[|\|)(foo|ba[rz])="(\w+)"(?=]]|\|)
```

Details:

- `(?:\[\[|\|)` - the content before (will be a part of the match,
  but not a part of any capturing group),
- `(foo|ba[rz])="(\w+)"` - *name* / *value* pair (with double quotes),
- `(?=]]|\|)` - the content after (this time expressed as a
  *positive lookahead*).

For a working example see https://regex101.com/r/dj51GS/1

Comment: [This solution](https://regex101.com/r/dj51GS/2) also matches key-values when outside of `[[` and `]]`.